# Displays buefy@0.4.5 extraneous `-- font-awesome@4.7.0 extraneous when using npm install buefy and npm install font-awesome

Tags: javascript, npm, font-awesome, bulma

When installing buefy and font-awesome it labels as **extraneous** and the folder is displayed with arrow with nothing in it. How to resolve this one.

like this

```
     +-- buefy@0.4.5  extraneous
     -- font-awesome@4.7.0  extraneous
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simply means that these modules are installed globally but do not appear in your `package.json`. Make sure to install locally.

To fix this, run `npm install -g {module} --save` to save it locally or manually include it in `package.json` 'dependencies' section.